# PHP Digest/Basic Auth default windows look

Tags: php, rest, digest, digest-authentication, http-digest

I have an application that uses REST API and I'm implementing Digest Authentication for the security scheme. The problem is, when I log into the application, I don't want the default user/pass windows to pop out every time a resource is consumed, but instead I want it to use the username and password that was written when logged in using the app log in form, so how do I do to use that information when the first 401 status response is received?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the authentication information in the request headers when the request is made against the resource.

Comment: But that's the problem: Because it's Digest Auth, I'm supposed to get a nonce, an opaque, and other variables from the server, before I can pass any credential, unless I'm getting something wrong.